# Excel files are opening with PowerPoint instead

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

When I first used a flash drive containing Excel files, Microsoft Excel was not installed on my computer.

So, Windows 7 opened it with PowerPoint and now all the Excel files on my flash drive open with PowerPoint as a media file. I have installed Microsoft Office, but it still opens as a media file.

What can I do?

Comment: What version of Excel did you install? It should have associated the file types with it during the install, unless there was a problem with the install. It is possible the files you have on your flash drive are not compatible with the version installed.

Comment: Often a user will accidentally do an 'Open With...' and make the association-change permanent.  It's not usually an installation issue.  Darth Android has a clear reply below.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change the associated program with a particular filetype, the quickest way is to simply `Right Click` on a file of the given type, select `Open With ...` from the menu, and then find the desired application in the dialog that pops up. Make sure to check `Always use the selected program to open this kind of file` to make the change persist!

Answer (score 0):

Right Click the file > Open With...> Select Microsoft Excel and make sure the box at the bottom "Always use the selected Program..." is checked.  If Excel isn't listed, click browse and select the excel.exe from \Program Files\Office